# .NET MAUI commands never get executed

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, maui

I have a view in .NET MAUI that has some buttons like this:

```
<Button Text="d2" Command="{Binding RollCommand}" CommandParameter="2" />
<Button Text="d4" Command="{Binding RollCommand}" CommandParameter="4" />
<Button Text="d6" Command="{Binding RollCommand}" CommandParameter="6" />
<Button Text="d8" Command="{Binding RollCommand}" CommandParameter="8" />
<Button Text="d10" Command="{Binding RollCommand}" CommandParameter="10" />
<Button Text="d12" Command="{Binding RollCommand}" CommandParameter="12" />
<Button Text="d20" Command="{Binding RollCommand}" CommandParameter="20" />
```

The data context is set up for the view above:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DiceRoller2"
             x:Class="DiceRoller2.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:DiceRollerViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    // ...
```

And the command is defined in this view model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace DiceRoller2
{
    [INotifyPropertyChanged]
    public partial class DiceRollerViewModel
    {
        public DiceRollerViewModel()
        {
            RollCommand = new Command<int>(Roll);
        }

        public int Dice { get; set; }

        public string Result { get; set; }

        public ICommand RollCommand { get; set; }

        public void Roll(int sides)
        {
            var rolls = new List<int>();
            for (var i = 0; i < Dice; i++)
            {
                rolls.Add(Random.Shared.Next(1, sides + 1));
            }
            Result = $"Rolled {Dice}d{sides} and got {string.Join(", ", rolls)} for a total of {rolls.Sum()}.";
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run the app, clicking the buttons does nothing; even if I set a breakpoint in the `Roll` method, it never gets hit, even though a breakpoint in the view model's constructor does get hit.

What could I be missing? Why is the command to roll the dice not executing? The WPF data binding debugging options in Visual Studio don't seem to apply to MAUI, unfortunately...

Comment: Are the Buttons in the ContentPage?

Comment: One possibility: Look at your code behind for that view. Make sure there isn't ALSO a `BindingContext = ...;` line there. May get unexpected result if a view sets BindingContext in BOTH xaml and c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it is recommended that we should use `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` when using `MVVM` in your MAUI project.

And then I think the issue is related to the `CommandParameter`, it should be a `String` type instead of `Integer`. You can refer to my below code snippets:

**1.** Install the nuget package `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` in your project.

**2.** **View:** MainPage.xaml

```
   <Button WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="50" Text="Add" Command="{Binding RollCommand} " CommandParameter="22"></Button>
```

In code-behind, don't forget to use binding with ViewModel:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new DiceRollerViewModel();
    }
```

**3.** **ViewModel:** DiceRollerViewModel.cs

When using `MVVM`, the VM should implement the `ObservableObject` as below:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MauiApptest01
{
    public class DiceRollerViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ICommand RollCommand { get; set; }

        public DiceRollerViewModel()
        {

            RollCommand = new Command<string>(Roll);
        }
        private void Roll(string sides)
        {
             Debug.WriteLine("Answer: This is a test "+ sides);
        }
    }
}
```

**4.** When clicking the button, the command is being triggered in your debug output like below :

```
Answer: This is a test22
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks! Changing the integer sides to a string let the Roll method run. Wonder why ICommand is generic if it only works with strings? But now even though the Roll method runs, the data binding for the Result property doesn't work, so the results of rolling the dice don't appear. The binding looks like this: `<Label Text="{Binding Path=Result}" />`

Comment: I was able to fix this by calling `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Result));` at the end of the `Roll` method, but I thought that the Community Toolkit would handle that for me. Oh well...

Comment: @ekolis - When using the nuget package, Inherit "ObservableObject" on the class, and then for binding your properties you use the attribute [ObserverableProperty] e.g. [ObservableProperty] private string _result; The above will bind your label named Result - It's clever to ignore the underscore & casing. - For the command use [RelayCommand] attribute and leave off the Command word of the method name: e.g. Command="{Binding RollCommand}" << In the XAML /*In the ViewModel*/ [RelayCommand] private async void Roll(string dice) { Result = "You rolled a 3"; }